Mean and Gauss curvatures of parallel surface
I am trying to find the curvatures of the "parallel surface":
$S_{\varepsilon}=\{p+\varepsilon N(p): p\in S\}$ where $S\subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is a regular surface with a regular parametrization $\omega (u,v)$.
I proved that $S_{\varepsilon}$ is a regular surface for certain values of $\varepsilon$ and I found that $X_{u}^{\varepsilon}=X_u-\varepsilon L_u$ and $X_{v}^{\varepsilon}=X_v-\varepsilon L_v$ (where $X_u$ is the derivative of $\omega$ with respect to the parameter $u$ and $L_u$ is the Weingarten operator applied to $X_u$, and same thing for $v$).
Then, to find the curvatures of $S_{\varepsilon}$, my idea was to compute the matrix of the Weingarten operator of the parallel surface with respect to the basis $\{X_{u}^{\varepsilon},X_{v}^{\varepsilon}\}$, using the fact that $N_{\varepsilon}=N$, but I found that $L^{\varepsilon}(X_{u}^{\varepsilon})=l_{u}^{u}X_{u}^{\varepsilon}+l_{u}^{v}X_{v}^{\varepsilon}$ and $L^{\varepsilon}(X_{v}^{\varepsilon})=l_{v}^{u}X_{u}^{\varepsilon}+l_{v}^{v}X_{v}^{\varepsilon}$ (where $l_{u}^{u}, l_{u}^{v}, l_{v}^{u}, l_{v}^{v}$ are the coefficients of the Weingarten operator of $S$, that is: $L(X_u)=l_{u}^{u}X_u+l_{u}^{v}X_v$ and $L(X_v)=l_{v}^{u}X_u+l_{v}^{v}X_v$). So, what I actually found is that the two surfaces have the same Weingarten operator, then the same curvatures. However, I know this is not true.
I have already seen solutions to this problem on this forum, but I still do not understand why my reasoning is wrong and how to solve the problem using the definitions of the mean curvature and the Gauss curvature respectively as the semi-trace and the determinant of the Weingarten operator.
Thanks for any help!
I write my computations here:
$L_{u}^{\varepsilon}=-\frac{\partial N}{\partial X_{u}^{\varepsilon}}=-\frac{\partial N}{X_{u}}+\varepsilon\frac{\partial N}{\partial L_{u}}=L_{u}+\varepsilon l_{u}^{u}\frac{\partial N}{\partial X_u}+\varepsilon l_{u}^{v}\frac{\partial N}{\partial X_v}$.
$\Longrightarrow L_{u}^{\varepsilon}=l_{u}^{u}X_u+l_{u}^{v}X_v-\varepsilon l_{u}^{u}L_u-\varepsilon l_{u}^{v}L_v=l_{u}^{u}(X_u-\varepsilon L_u)+l_{u}^{v}(x_v-\varepsilon L_v)$.
$\Longrightarrow L_{u}^{\varepsilon}=l_{u}^{u}X_{u}^{\varepsilon}+l_{u}^{v}X_{v}^{\varepsilon}$.
With the same calculations I obtain:
$L_{v}^{\varepsilon}=l_{v}^{u}X_{u}^{\varepsilon}+l_{v}^{v}X_{v}^{\varepsilon}$

Please edit your post to include the details of your computations, as the mistake obviously lies therein.

The mistake is very subtle. In fact, the tangent spaces of $S$ and $S_\epsilon$ at corresponding points — although equal — are related by a non-trivial linear mapping, and losing track of that here makes one think the two Weingarten operators are equal when they’re not. I would recommend simplifying this a bit by assuming you’ve parametrized with $u,v$ curves the lines of curvature (so $L$ and $L_\epsilon$ are both diagonal). You can find this approach in one or two of my answers to the same question about parallel surfaces, e,g., here.
Here is the point: Your equation $N_\epsilon = N$ is just wrong. These are actually functions on different surfaces, although we think of them as functions of $u$ and $v$. (The Weingarten operator is actually a self-adjoint linear map from $T_pS$ to itself, even though we are used to calculating in terms of $u,v$ coordinates.)   What is correct is the statement $N_\epsilon(p+\epsilon N(p)) = N(p)$. More succinctly, letting $f(p) = p + \epsilon N(p)$, we have $N_\epsilon\circ f = N$. Then chain rule then tells us that $dN_\epsilon\circ df = dN$, so
$-L_\epsilon\circ(I-\epsilon L) = -L$. That is,
$$L_\epsilon = L(I-\epsilon L)^{-1}.$$ If $v$ is an eigenvector of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then you can easily check that $L_\epsilon(v)=\dfrac{\lambda}{1-\epsilon\lambda} v$.
